# How to sort an array field after modifying an element, i.e. calling $sort outside of a $push?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

`$sort` can only be used after `$push`ing a new element to an array field. the Goal is to sort after modifying an element of an array during an update call.

How can this be done?

Comment: "$sort can only be used after $push" - where did you get this?

Comment: Is so, can you answer the question and give an example of how $sort can be used after $set is used to modified an element of an arrray?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$push` operation with an empty `$each` modifier to sort an array without adding any elements to it, for example:

```js
db.collection.updateOne(
  {},
  {
    $push: {
      arr: {
        $each: [],
        $sort: 1
      }
    } 
  }
);
```

To change an element and sort in a single update command, you can do the following, in this example changing the third element of `arr` to equal 10 and then sorting (added based on comment):

```js
db.collection.updateOne(
  {},
  [
    {
      $set: {
        'arr': {
          $sortArray: {
            input: {
              $concatArrays: [
                { $slice: ['$arr', 2] },
                [10],
                { $slice: ['$arr', 3, { $size: '$arr' }] },
              ]
            },
            sortBy: 1
          },
        }
      }
    },
  ]
);
```

Comment: But about modifying the element? This does not modify the element.

Comment: Added an example of changing an element and sorting in a single update command.